# how to filter certain rows from datatable based on some value which should not be added to the table display too

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am rendering datatable in my jsp page. datatable receives json of array of objects from servlet. Now I have one parameter called id which should not be added to the table but i need to filter rows based on that id how to achieve this??

Here is my ajax call

```
var table;
function fetchClients(id){

    //alert('Id received:'+id);
    $('document').ready(function(){

            if(table)
                table.destroy();
        table=$('#example').dataTable({
            "processing":true,
            "serverSide":true,
            "ajax":{
                "url":"/DashBoard/FetchClients",
                "dataType":"json",
                "data": {alertId: id},
                "type":"POST"
                },
                "aoColumns":[
                    {"mData": "clientId"},
                    {"mData":"clientName"},
                    {"mData": "AliasName"},
                    {"mData": "Status"},
                    {"mData": "Time"},
                    {"mData": "Date"}
                ]
            });

    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One quick but bad solution to go with is hiding the column of ID

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hidden column with the information that you want to hide.
jQuery datatable provides an option called `column.visible`, and you can use it to reduce the amount of data shown on screen, keeping essencial information for filtering purposes.

To use this, just set the option `visible` to `false` when defining the options for your table:

```
$('#my-databale').dataTable( {
    "columnDefs": [
        {
            "targets": [ 2 ],
            "visible": false,
            "searchable": false
        },
        {
            "targets": [ 3 ],
            "visible": false
        }
    ]
});
```

If you want to do this dinamically, like a switch on/off, you will need to provide the column name of your table, and then pass a boolean as parameter to the method `visible(bool)` to show or hide this column.

Basically, something like this:

```
var 
    // Column $
    column_id = >> The reference of your column here <<,

    // Get the column
    column = $('#my-datatable').column( column_id );

// Voilà! Now you see me, now you not!
column.visible( false ); // You can pass true or false for show/hide your column
```

For further information, check the datatable documentation:

**Hidden columns**
http://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/hidden_columns.html

**Show / hide columns dynamically**
http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html

Hope that helps ;)

Comment: is it we should write columDefs sepeartely or can we append it after "aoColumns" ??

Comment: If you opt to use `aoColumns`, you can set the option `bVisible` as `false` to hide the column. Bear in mind that if you use `aoColumns`, you must specify a rule for all columns because the length of this array must be equal to the number of columns in the original HTML table. You can use `null` where you wish to use only the default values and automatically detected options. Check it out this link to get more info and 
examples http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns

Comment: Alright that sounds good and working now.. But My biggest headache now is I need to filter the rows when i click on a button. The buttons are more and based on the buttons rows also will differ how can i achieve this//

Comment: First you will need to define the column where you want to search in. For example, you want to search some id inside `id` column. Then you may use the method `column().search()`. You select the columns where you want to search, then call `search( search_argument )` passing the argument you want to find as parameter. By the end, you use the method `draw()` to render your new table. You can use something like this: `column([0,1,2]).search('John Doe').draw()`. Check this link to see a very good example: https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html

Comment: In the example mentioned by you.. A search field from table itself is used.. But I need to search when button not have link with table and it is not of type "text"

Comment: You can put this method inside a click listener from wherever button you need to. Since you will search by ids, you can do something like this: `button.on('click', function() {   dataTable.column([0]).search(id).draw();   });`, where button is the jQuery selector for your search button, [0] is the column with the id, and id is the value you want to search for. You will need to edit the above example to fit to your problem (:

Comment: Instead of that now Im trying to search using row_id. now Im setting DT_RowId to that alertId still Im stuck how to search rows.. The example given is $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
        function( settings, data, dataIndex, origData ) {
          return origData.DT_RowId === sortId;
        }); inside my click event function.. but nothing is happening.......

Comment: Your dataTable is loaded dinamically? If yes, I would recommend you to add the search argument to your ajax request and retrieve just the rows that match. As an example, you could use http://www.datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html or a jQuery.ajax(), where its callback will be the data to draw in dataTable. It seems that "it is not possible to do a client search when server side is enabled" (http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/23646/fn-datatable-ext-search-push-doesn-t-work). Otherwise, the method explained above will fit.

Comment: I got solution dude.. I cant call ajax everytime as my db is loaded heavily.. so i have given all the cells an id using alertid and status together[concatenate] and i am using jquery find method to search.. its working good.. Thanks for showing interests :-)